# How to annotate Django view's methods?

Tags: python, django, annotations, type-hinting

I'd like to use Python [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) in my Django project. What's the proper way to annotate `get`/`post` methods of a simple [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) in Django?

I've searched the Django code itself but it doesn't seem to contain any type hints.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[UPDATE 15/12/2022]:** Well I have forgotten this answer, but it seems that you don't need a project that is not maintained for the last 6 years **if you use Python 3.6+**.

Just use [typing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html) (if needed) and type hints as normal.

Example:

```
def get(self, request: HttpRequest, question_id: typing.Optional[str] = None) -> HttpResponse:
    # code here
```

---

There exists this repository which may interest you: https://github.com/machinalis/mypy-django 
which will allow you to use annotations like so:

```
def get(self, request: HttpRequest, question_id: str) -> HttpResponse:
```

Answer (score 3):

If using function-based views, and if you don't want or need mypy-django, you can do:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def some_fbv(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    ....
    return foo

def some_json_producing_fbv(request: HttpRequest) -> JsonResponse:
    ...
    return foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Django stubs is well maintained package, https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs.

```
import typing as t

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse, JsonResponse, 
HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import MyForm

# type alias when response is one of these types
RedirectOrResponse = t.Union[HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse]


class MyFormView(View):
    form_class = MyForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'form_template.html'

    def get(self, request: HttpRequest, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> HttpResponse:
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request: HttpRequest, *args: tuple[Any], 
                **kwargs: dict[str, t.Union[int, str]]) -> RedirectOrResponse:
        form: MyForm = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             # <process form cleaned data>
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

- `HttpRequest` maps to request variable in the function or method.
- `HttpResponse, JsonResponse, StreamingResponse, Redirect` will be value returned by the view function/method.
- `*args, **kwargs` is easy and tricky, since it can be of *any* tuple of values or dictionary of values. `*args: Any` or `*args: tuple[Any]`(you can also use specific types if you know about it). The same applies to `**kwargs`.
- Whenever the class is passed or returned, use `type[cls]`.

More Examples: https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/tree/master/tests